# Change certain value in all unique keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I am trying to code http trigger function which would change the certain value in every unique key (user id). I have written something but the output is not what I need. Instead of changing existing values, it creates new user id.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.picksReset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const ref = admin.database().ref()

  const usersPicked = []

  ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(childSnap => {

      ref.child('/users/{userId}').push({picksDone: "0"})
      console.log("Changing value...")

    })
  })

  res.send("Done!")

})
```

An image of my database...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.push()` creates a new child with a pushId. Instead, use `.update()`. See details in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update). If you're looking to change the child `picksDone` in each user, you can do so like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.picksReset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const ref = admin.database().ref()

  const usersPicked = []

  ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(childSnap => {
      const key = childSnap.key
      ref.child(`users/${key}`).update({picksDone: "0"})
      console.log("Changing value...")

    })
  })
  res.send("Done!")
})
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I really need to get into Firebase more deeply... :)